# C++, error when using iterator for a map container that is pointed to. map/set iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, iterator

I am getting this error when trying to iterate over a map that is pointed to by another object. It works when I am not using a pointer. (Iterating over the member map "pieces") I am therefore wondering what to do, or if it's not possible to iterate through the map like this ? :

```
Board * Board::ccBoard(){

Board * newBoard = new Board();
map<Vec2, Piece>::iterator it;
for (it = newBoard->pieces.begin(); it != newBoard->pieces.end(); ++it)
    newBoard->removePiece(it->first);
return newBoard;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the error and where is it?

Comment: Does `removePiece()` remove the entry associated with the key `it->first` from the `pieces` `map` ? If so, `it` will be invalidated.

Comment: Show us the `removePiece()` method

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and get a "Debug Assertion Failed" in ..\vc\include\xtree line 256 : #if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
  if (this->_Getcont() == 0
   || this->_Ptr == 0
   || _Mytree::_Isnil(this->_Ptr))
   { // report error
   _DEBUG_ERROR("map/set iterator not incrementable");
   _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
   }

Comment: void Board::removePiece(Vec2 posd){
 pieces.erase(posd);
 board[posd.x][posd.y] = false;
}

Comment: I tried commenting out the removePiece() method, and then it works, so I guess there's something wrong with that.

Comment: hmjd : Ah, ok, so I can't remove the entries like that ? Is there any other way I can remove them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removePiece()` function removes the element that `it` is referring to, invalidating `it`. An attempt is then made to increment `it` resulting in the assertion failure. From [`map::erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

I am unsure what the intention of the `for` loop is, it appears that it would effectively empty the `map` in which case just use [`map::clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear):

```
newBoard->pieces.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix, get rid of the `++it` in the for loop and replace `it->first` by `it++->first`.

(This will increment the iterator and call erase() using a copy.)